# How to find periodic solutions for dynamical system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have the Hamiltonian system given by $$H=\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{3}x^3+xy^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2$$ Using computer software I managed to plot the dynamical system in the phase plane. I am aware that the equilibrium point given by $(0,0)$ is a centre of the system and graphing shows that there are certainly periodic solutions close to this equilibrium point but I'm not sure exactly how to give a description of the region in which all phase paths are periodic.

I am thinking to use Poincare-Benedixson to try and find a invariant compact set in the plane with no equilibrium points to show that each path must be periodic and it is clear that around $(0,0)$ this is true but I'm not sure how "close" we need to be and how to actually write down a set of the form $\{(x,y)\in \Bbb{R^2}:\text{Some restirction on x,y}\}$ such that the phase path through $(x,y)$ is periodic.

Any help?

Comment: *Which* dynamical system? There is none in the question...

Comment: The Dynamical system given by $\dot{x}=H_y$ and $\dot{y}=-H_x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for the short answer, but I believe [the answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1761569/how-to-find-the-straight-line-paths-of-saddle-points-for-a-nonlinear-hamiltonian/1762558#1762558) contains a lot of useful information, as the question is about the same Hamiltonian system.

**Hint**: The trapping region seems to be an equilateral triangle. An equilateral triangle has a symmetry group $C_3$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group)), which just means that you can rotate the triangle over an angle $\frac{2 \pi}{3}$ to obtain the same triangle. It is *very* worthwhile to test if the dynamical system associated with your Hamiltonian has the same symmetry. Suppose that the system is indeed invariant under such rotations, how could you use this to show the existence of closed orbits?

Comment: Okay thank you I shall take a look. I didn't see that somebody had posted from the same resource as me otherwise I would not post sorry.

Comment: I just had a read over it and I don't understand what the $x(t)=\sin t$ is about I can't see how that is relevant? Sorry for not understanding. Would you please elaborate on how I can find the periodic orbits? Would it just be the set of points within the triangle defined with edges being the 3 saddle points?

Comment: Yes, indeed. My goal in the original answer was for the poster of that question to find out him/herself that periodic solutions manifest themselves as closed orbits (loops) in the phase plane. Your question is about finding a suitable trapping region. I'll add a hint for the periodic orbits to my answer.

Comment: Yes that makes sense since the start point must be reached again and then if you had a pencil for example you would keep drawing over the same line over and over. I am still finding difficulty in finding the region on which these phase lines will be periodic though hopefully the hint might give me some insight.

Comment: Assume the triangle is a compact invariant set if we remove the fixed point $(0,0)$ from the inside then we have a compact invariant set with no fixed points hence by Poincare-Benedixson theorem we have that each phase path through any point it the triangle is either a periodic orbit or tends to one? Is that along the right lines.

Comment: It is along the right lines; using Poincaré–Bendixson in this way, you can prove the existence of a periodic orbit. However, if you use the symmetry argument, you can prove that there is a one-parameter family of periodic orbits within the triangle, as you can see in the phase plane plot.